# Update textPath after tween transition in D3

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, text, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to put together an animated sunburst diagram that can zoom and change between data representations, based some examples I've found: [Vasco](https://bl.ocks.org/vasturiano/12da9071095fbd4df434e60d52d2d58d), [Visual Cinnamon](https://www.visualcinnamon.com/2015/09/placing-text-on-arcs.html), [David Richard](https://bl.ocks.org/denjn5/e1cdbbe586ac31747b4a304f8f86efa5) etc.

I'm not able to get the animation part to properly work. The arcs are updating, but the text labels aren't. Any advice? Also, I'm pretty new to this so I'd appreciate any other tips or advice on how to structure my code as well.

```js
// Variables
const width = window.innerWidth;
const height = window.innerHeight;
const radius = (Math.min(width, height) / 2) - 5;
const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);
const x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 2 * Math.PI]).clamp(true);
const y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius]);

// Create our sunburst data structure and size it.
const partition = d3.partition();

// Size our <svg> element
const svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
  .style('width', '100vw')
  .style('height', '100vh')
  .attr('viewBox', `${-width / 2} ${-height / 2} ${width} ${height}`)
  .attr("id", "container");

arc = d3.arc()
  .startAngle(function(d) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x0)));
  })
  .endAngle(function(d) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x1)));
  })
  .innerRadius(function(d) {
    return Math.max(0, y(d.y0));
  })
  .outerRadius(function(d) {
    return Math.max(0, y(d.y1));
  });

// JSON data
    var nodeData = {
        "name": "TOPICS", "children": [{
            "name": "Topic A",
            "children": [{"name": "Sub A1", "size": 4}, {"name": "Sub A2", "size": 4}]
        }, {
            "name": "Topic B",
            "children": [{"name": "Sub B1", "size": 3}, {"name": "Sub B2", "size": 3}, {
                "name": "Sub B3", "size": 3}]
        }, {
            "name": "Topic C",
            "children": [{"name": "Sub A1", "size": 4}, {"name": "Sub A2", "size": 4}]
        }]
    };


createVisualization()

// Main function to draw and set up the visualization
function createVisualization() {
  // Find the root node, calculate the node.value, and sort our nodes by node.value
  root = d3.hierarchy(nodeData)
    .sum(function(d) {
      return d.size;
    })
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.value - a.value;
    });
  original = root;
  partition(root);

  // Add a <g> element for each node in thd data, then append <path> elements and draw lines based on the arc
  // variable calculations. Last, color the lines and the slices.
  slices = svg.selectAll('path')
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter().append('g').attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", focusOn);

  slices.append('path')
    .attr('class', 'main-arc')
    .attr("id", function(d, i) {
      return "arc_" + i;
    })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style('stroke', '#fff')
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name);
    })
    .each(function(d, i) {
      const halfPi = Math.PI / 2;
      const angles = [Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x0))) - halfPi, Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x1))) - halfPi];

      const r = Math.max(0, (y(d.y0) + y(d.y1)) / 2);

      const middleAngle = (angles[1] + angles[0]) / 2;
      const invertDirection = middleAngle > 0 && middleAngle < Math.PI; // On lower quadrants write text ccw
      if (invertDirection) {
        angles.reverse();
      }

      const path = d3.path();
      path.arc(0, 0, r, angles[0], angles[1], invertDirection);

      //Create a new invisible arc that the text can flow along
      d3.select(this).append("path")
        .attr("class", "hiddenArcs")
        .attr("id", "hiddenArc_" + i)
        .attr("d", path.toString())
        .style("fill", "none");
    });

  text = slices.append("text")
    .attr("class", "arcText");

  text.append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
      return "#hiddenArc_" + i;
    })
    .attr('startOffset', '50%')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke', '#fff')
    .style('stroke-width', 5)
    .style('stroke-linejoin', 'round');

  text.append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) {
      return "#hiddenArc_" + i;
    })
    .attr('startOffset', '50%');

  slices.selectAll("textPath")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.parent ? d.data.name : ""
    });

  // Redraw the Sunburst Based on User Input
  d3.selectAll(".sizeSelect").on("click", build);
}

function build() {
  // Determine how to size the slices.
  if (this.value === "size") {
    root.sum(function(d) {
      return d.size;
    });
  } else {
    root.count();
  }

  // Calculate the sizes of each arc that we'll draw later.
  partition(root);

  slices.selectAll("path.main-arc").transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", arcTweenData);
  slices.selectAll("path.hiddenArcs").transition().duration(750).attrTween("d", hiddenArcTweenData);

  slices.selectAll("textPath")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.parent ? d.data.name : ""
    });
}

// Respond to slice click.
function focusOn(d) {
  original = d;
  svg.selectAll("path").transition().duration(1000).attrTween("d", arcTweenZoom(d))
}

// When zooming: interpolate the scales.
function arcTweenZoom(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x0, d.x1]),
    yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y0, 1]), // [d.y0, 1]
    yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y0 ? 40 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i ? function(t) {
      return arc(d);
    } : function(t) {
      x.domain(xd(t));
      y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t));
      return arc(d);
    };
  };
}

// When switching data: interpolate the arcs in data space.
function arcTweenData(a, i) {
  // (a.x0s ? a.x0s : 0) -- grab the prev saved x0 or set to 0 (for 1st time through)
  // avoids the stash() and allows the sunburst to grow into being
  // var oi = d3.interpolate({ x0: (a.x0s ? a.x0s : 0), x1: (a.x1s ? a.x1s : 0) }, a);
  var oi = d3.interpolate({
    x0: (a.x0s ? a.x0s : 0),
    x1: (a.x1s ? a.x1s : 0)
  }, a);

  function tween(t) {
    var b = oi(t);
    a.x0s = b.x0;
    a.x1s = b.x1;
    return arc(b);
  }
  if (i == 0) {
    // If we are on the first arc, adjust the x domain to match the root node
    // at the current zoom level. (We only need to do this once.)
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [original.x0, original.x1]);
    return function(t) {
      x.domain(xd(t));
      return tween(t);
    };
  } else {
    return tween;
  }
}

function hiddenArcTweenData(a, i) {
  // (a.x0s ? a.x0s : 0) -- grab the prev saved x0 or set to 0 (for 1st time through)
  var oi = d3.interpolate({
    x0: (a.x0s ? a.x0s : 0),
    x1: (a.x1s ? a.x1s : 0)
  }, a);

  function tween(t) {
    var b = oi(t);
    a.x0s = b.x0;
    a.x1s = b.x1;
    return middleArc(b);
  }
  if (i == 0) {
    // If we are on the first arc, adjust the x domain to match the root node
    // at the current zoom level. (We only need to do this once.)
    var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [original.x0, original.x1]);
    return function(t) {
      x.domain(xd(t));
      return tween(t);
    };
  } else {
    return tween;
  }
}

function middleArc(d) {
  const halfPi = Math.PI / 2;
  const angles = [Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x0))) - halfPi, Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x1))) - halfPi];

  const r = Math.max(0, (y(d.y0) + y(d.y1)) / 2);

  const middleAngle = (angles[1] + angles[0]) / 2;
  const invertDirection = middleAngle > 0 && middleAngle < Math.PI; // On lower quadrants write text ccw
  if (invertDirection) {
    angles.reverse();
  }

  const path = d3.path();
  path.arc(0, 0, r, angles[0], angles[1], invertDirection);
  return path;
}
```

```css
body {
  @import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fakt:400,600";
  font-family: 'Fakt', fakt;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 960px;
  height: 700px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node .main-arc {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.node .hidden-arc {
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke: #000;
}

.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: middle;
  fill: #000
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sunburst</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sunburst.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <label>
        <input class="sizeSelect" type="radio" name="mode" value="count" checked/> Count </label>
      <label>
        <input class="sizeSelect" type="radio" name="mode" value="size" /> Size </label>
      <div id="chart">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="sunburst.js"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS code on line 97 says:

```
  d3.select(this).append("path")
```

This will add the `.hiddenArcs` path as a child of the `.main-arc` `<path>`, rather than the parent `<g>`. This makes it invalid SVG, but it also makes the selector `slices.selectAll("path.hiddenArcs")` return an empty set. So, the hidden arcs never tween, and so the text stays where it is.

Changing line 97 so the hidden arc is added to the path's parent node, rather than the path, fixes this:

```
  d3.select(this.parentNode).append("path")
```